# How to get VC++ include directories programmatically?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-extensions

I am writing a Visual Studio extension in C# and I need to get the project properties. More particularly, I am looking for an API allowing to get the **expanded value** of "Configuration Properties > VC++ Directories > Include directories", or alternatively how to get the expanded value of $(VC_IncludePath) or $(WindowsSDK_IncludePath). More generally how to get the **expanded value** of any variable set by the IDE or the compiler.

I could find some posts telling how to get the properties present in the vcxproj file (from IVsSolution and IVsBuildPropertyStorage). However, these properties I am looking for seem to set by the IDE or the compiler and are not present in the vcxproj file. And I could not find any post about that.

More generally, I need to get the expanded value of:

- Configuration Properties > General > Project Defaults > Configuration Type
- Configuration Properties > VC++ Directories > Include directories
- Configuration Properties > C/C++ > General > Additional Include directories
- Configuration Properties > C/C++ > General > Additional #using directories
- Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Preprocessor > Preprocessor Definitions
- Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Preprocessor > Undefine Preprocessor Definitions
- Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Preprocessor > Undefine All Preprocessor Definitions
- Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Preprocessor > Ignore Standard Include Paths
- Configuration Properties > NMake > IntelliSense > Preprocessor Definitions
- Configuration Properties > NMake > IntelliSense > Include Search Path

*Note that Project.ConfigurationManager.ActiveConfiguration.Properties was null in my case. It was successfully passing through VCProject.ActiveConfiguration.*

> **Solution**:
>   Thanks to @Lance hints, I ended up to the global C++ Project Configuration documentation page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/property-pages-visual-cpp. It gives the ways to access to the different configuration settings I was looking for. Plus all specific links mentioned by Lance in his answer.

Comment: I have found more documentation around here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/property-pages-visual-cpp?view=vs-2017 that explain that tokens like $(VC_IncludePath) or $(WindowsSDK_IncludePath) are macros. There is more info on how to set new macros or see values in the GUI but not how to get their values programmatically :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to get VC++ include directories programmatically?

You can use [VSPlatform.IncludeDirectories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.vcprojectengine.vcplatform.includedirectories?view=visualstudiosdk-2017#Microsoft_VisualStudio_VCProjectEngine_VCPlatform_IncludeDirectories) property to get what you want. (We need to manually add reference to `Microsoft.VisualStudio.VCProjectEngine.dll` by right-click project=>add reference=>extension reference...)

And for those properties like [AdditionalIncludeDirectories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.vcprojectengine.vcclcompilertool.additionalincludedirectories?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) , [AdditionalUsingDirectories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.vcprojectengine.vcclcompilertool.additionalusingdirectories?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) ,  [PreprocessorDefinitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.vcprojectengine.vcclcompilertool.preprocessordefinitions?view=visualstudiosdk-2017)... under `C/C++` tab you can use [VCCLCompilerTool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.vcprojectengine.vcclcompilertool?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) Interface to access them.

For the properties under `NMake` tab, use the [VCNMakeTool.IncludeSearchPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.vcprojectengine.vcnmaketool.includesearchpath?view=visualstudiosdk-2017#Microsoft_VisualStudio_VCProjectEngine_VCNMakeTool_IncludeSearchPath) and [VCNMakeTool.PreprocessorDefinitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.vcprojectengine.vcnmaketool.preprocessordefinitions?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) to access them.

**In addition:** You may get help from these two blogs from **Carlos J**, [one](https://www.mztools.com/articles/2014/MZ2014004.aspx) and [two](https://www.mztools.com/articles/2014/MZ2014004.aspx). Thanks to him!

**Update1:**

Those apis or peroperties from `VS SDK` are used to get the values we see in `VS UI`:

[image]

We can see $(...) in VS UI, and we can use those properties above to get them using VS SDK. It's expected behavior that those properties return macros like `$(VC_IncludePath)`... To get the expanded value of `$(VC_IncludePath)`, it's not job of VS SDK, it's [MSBuild scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild?view=vs-2019) cause the macros are defined and imported by msbuild targets and props files.

Comment: Hi Lance! Good to hear back from you :-) I will try that right now. Do these API provide expanded values for $(VC_IncludePath) or $(WindowsSDK_IncludePath) (default value for Include directories)? Thanks!

Comment: I just tried and the first step works. I get full objects when using VCPlatform. Unfortunately, internal macros are not expanded and I get IncludeDirectories = '$(VC_IncludePath);$(WindowsSDK_IncludePath);'. How can I get the expanded value for these macros? Thanks!

Comment: @Stephane I think it's impossible to get the expanded value of the macros using the api from VS SDK, cause the macros come from imported props or targets file, and that's [msbuild scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/msbuild). No api in VS SDK can really expand the value for us.